# Find sets of strings that a human could easily confuse

Tags: algorithm, text

Given a list of strings (specifically *names*), is there an algorithm detecting items that could easily be confused by a human, eg. below, 3, 4 and 5 would be most likely confused, 6 and 7 less easily, 1 and 2 quite unlikely, and 8 has no equal. If finding sets are difficult, pairs would be acceptable.

```
1. Joe Average
2. Joe Beverage
3. Michael Andersen
4. Michael Anderson
5. Micheal Anderson
6. Steve Cook
7. Steve Look
8. Xena: Warrior Princess
```

To complicate matters, character position must be considered, because a human would more easily spot a character difference in the beginning of a word/string, than one in the middle, eg.

```
1. Pink Floyd
2. Bink Floyd
3. Rolling Stones
4. Rolllng Stones
```

Furthermore, it's more difficult to spot a character difference in a long string than in a short:

```
1. Florence Griffith-Joyner
2. Florence Grifflth-Joyner
3. J. Lo
4. J. Law
```

Maybe there would be even other aspects that must be taken into consideration, based on how humans read, how the eye moves, etc. and other things that may cause erroneous identification.

The only related algorithm I know is Levenshtein, which assimilates pairs a human never would.

Ways to simplify the problem (what I initially had in mind):

- Assume a fixed-width display font
- Compare single character to single character
- Assume a small character set with mostly differing characters

Ways to complicate the problem (which should be avoided if the code size explodes):

- Look beyond single character comparison, eg. compare small RN to small M
- Consider the entire Unicode set with all its [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph)

Comment: Interesting problem. The soundx and metaphone algorithms solve this problem for speech, but I'm not aware of a "looks like" algorithm for text.

Comment: Am I the only one who sometimes has a difficult time differentiating between "m" and "rn" in written text? Depending on the font, it's difficult to tell "tom" from "torn".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use weighted edit distance, where different edits have different costs. So changing "O" to "E" would have a low cost, but changing "C" to "L" would have higher cost. This approach requires a table of all edits with corresponding weights.

This is one of the techniques used in spell-correction applications, and you might be able to find existing weights for this, or learn your own weights with a spell-correction training dataset.

Comment: I follow you on the weighted edit distance, but is there any way to do this with a screenful of simple code logic, without going full OCR/ML?

Comment: @forthrin No, because this problem requires in-depth knowledge of how English orthography works. The fact that "Stephen" and "Steven" are much more ambiguous than "Pent" and "Vent" is not inherent to any algorithm.

Comment: So basically develop a two-dimensional lookup table using some advanced, possibly CPU-intensive method, then write a fast Levenshtein-like algorithm which gives each character replacement a score from the table rather than just +1? Has anyone done either part already, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel? PS! And what about the character position thing?

Comment: A friend of mine who is a computational linguist said, "You would need something like the Levenshtein distance metric but calibrated by empirical data on actual reading performance. This is linguistics, not computer science." In other words, research to determine the weightings, prior to developing any code.

Comment: The problem with distance metrics based solutions is that it's an n^2 problem: you have to compare every string against every other string. If you could develop a SOUNDEX-like algorithm, it would convert each string into some canonical form so that "Anderson" and "Andersen" resolved to the same thing. You could then use an O(1) direct lookup. Whether that's possible to accomplish is something else entirely.

Comment: @Sneftel: Stephen and Steven *sound* alike, but they are rather different visually. On the other hand, a human may still quite easily mix up the two, with several possible causes (being in a hurry, being unsure how Stephen spells his name and thinking it's just you who's being forgetful or dumb, etc.) So this problem is more complex than I initially imagined... Then there is also being drunk, being teary-eyed, having misplaced your glasses, having dyslexia, etc. which I think would be outside the scope of the initial problem, and more of an extraordinary Accessibility issue.